# How to store user uploaded files with only client side encryption?

Tags: encryption, storage, client-side

I want to build an app where users upload files. But the owners of the server should never be able to have access to any data from the files, only encrypted content.

If I had to implement it myself using Java, I would do something like:

- symmetric encryption for the files using a random key per file (or per user because I don't need per file access control). The random key is then asymmetrically encrypted (one time for each user needing access to the file) and stored along the file on the server
- Users have a password encrypting their randomly generated on account creation private key stored on the server along with the public key.
- The user password hash (not the password itself) is also used as an authentication password to avoid having multiple passwords but also to avoid sending the user password to the server (the server then normally computes and compares the salted hash of this hash of the password)

How can I implement a custom app like this (using libraries?, running additional servers with http APIs?, something else?) ?

I found https://www.minio.io/features.html, an http server with s3 compatible rest APIs which has "Both server side and client side encryption are supported" but couldn't find enough documentation on the client side encryption.

Comment: `How can I implement a custom app like this` - it is still not clear what are you asking for. In your case there should be an encryption key per file if you want to share the files). Are you as well looking for storage solution or what?

Comment: I'm particularly looking for implementation strategies that are quicker/simpler/have fewer bugs than writing it directly using e.g. the java standard library. For example "Install project X on a separate server, it has http APIs that handle the crypto and write your frontend calling these APIs. or "Use library Y, it provides most of the functionality you want to achieve." But "Base your project on the standard library of any modern language, it's the best you can do" is good to know too. I would think that the system I want to build should be already almost existing but maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: Opinion based answers and searching for tools are discouraged on this forum. Regardless that - you may have a look at AWS SDK, it supports clients side encryption (with KMS or client-provided key). Then you could use any S3 compliant storage (aws s3, minio, ibm object storage,..)

Comment: Thank you. What should I do with these question ? Delete it ?